# why does my complete table shown when i enter space more than 4 times in my search script

Tags: php, search

hello every one i have a simple phpmysql search engine script its working very fine but i found a big problem in it the problem is whenever blank space is entered more than four times in a search box it displays complete data of my table please tell me how to resolve this problem and yes if two or space is added after some string then also this problem occur.

```
$button = $_GET ['submit'];
$search = $_GET ['search']; 
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Invalid search";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","9889922527");
mysql_select_db("specifications");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
@$x++;
if($x==1)

@$construct .="keyword LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keyword LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}

$constructs ="SELECT * FROM search WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($constructs);

@$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>";
else
{ 

echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

$per_page = 20;
@$start = $_GET['start'];
$max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE $construct  LIMIT $start,     $per_page");

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
{
$image = $runrows['image'];
$name = $runrows ['name'];
$price = $runrows ['price'];
$url = $runrows ['url'];
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='search.css' type='text/css' />";
echo "<div class='cat-logo'><img width='200' height='180' src='$image' /><br/><a       href='$url'><font class='cat-head'><b>$name</b></font></a><br/><font class='cat-pr'>$price</font></div>" ;
//echo "<a href='$url'><b>$name</b></a><br>$price<br><a href='$url'>$url</a><p>";

}
```

Comment: Nothing that searching for `'` won't fix. I suspect your Javascript triggers on at least 3 characters, and you end up searching for `keyword LIKE '%%' AND keyword LIKE '%%' AND keyword LIKE '%%'`.

Comment: i am not using any js can you please tell me how to resolve this don't give me the code but only a small hint

Comment: `$search = trim($search); if(strlen($search)<=1) echo "Invalid search";`

Comment: @darc Try echoing back the generated SQL, that should give some hints. At the very least also, you'll want to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to understand and cleanup your code (although some if/else loops seems to be unclosed in your example). Added some minimal escaping and added the trim (as suggested in the comments) to prevent the selection of all data. I also added a limit 1000 (to limit the amount of results a query could max generate:

```
$button = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submit']);
$search = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search'])); 

if(strlen($search)<=1) {
  echo "Invalid search";
} else {
  echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","9889922527");
  mysql_select_db("specifications");

  $search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);

  $x = 0;
  $construct = null;
  foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
  {
    $x++;
    if($x==1) {
      $construct .="keyword LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    } else {
      $construct .="AND keyword LIKE '%$search_each%'";
    }

    $constructs ="SELECT * FROM search WHERE $construct";
    $run = mysql_query($constructs);

    @$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);

    if ($foundnum==0) {
      echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.</br></br>";
    } else { 
      echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

      $per_page = 20;
      @$start = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['start']);
      $max_pages = ceil($foundnum / $per_page);
      if(!$start) {
        $start=0; 
        $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM search WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");

        while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
        {
          $image = $runrows['image'];
          $name = $runrows ['name'];
          $price = $runrows ['price'];
          $url = $runrows ['url'];
          echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='search.css' type='text/css' />";
          echo "<div class='cat-logo'><img width='200' height='180' src='$image' /><br/><a       href='$url'><font class='cat-head'><b>$name</b></font></a><br/><font class='cat-pr'>$price</font></div>" ;
          //echo "<a href='$url'><b>$name</b></a><br>$price<br><a href='$url'>$url</a><p>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would like to note that you use @param (probably to prevent notices about undefined vars?) Don't do this; declare them in front (like I did with the $x and the $construct (as an example). Prevent using @ as you will regret it in time. It suppresses all errors so debugging will be nearly impossible.